# Detailed XML Documentation for field. Does it possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xml-documentation

I have define a callback field and event property for it:

```
private Action<int, int, TaskCallbackArgs> _callbackEvent    
/// <summary>
/// Provides a callback event for task.
/// </summary>
public event Action<int, int, TaskCallbackArgs> CallbackEvent
{
  add
  {
    _callbackEvent += value;
  }
  remove
  {
    _callbackEvent -= value;
  }
}
```

In my code I have invoke the `_callbackEvent`. All right, but when I type `_callbackEvent(` VS show me  IntelliSense that my method want `(int arg1, int arg2, TaskCallbackArgs arg3)` arguments.
When I open this code some time later I don't remember what is arg1, arg2 and arg3.

**Is there a way to use XML Documentation for field as following?**

```
/// <summary>
/// Description
/// </summary>
/// <param name="current">Param description...</param>
/// <param name="total">Param description...</param>
/// <param name="additional">Param description...</param>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action<int, int, TaskCallbackArgs>` is a delegate type that takes three parameters.
You can write an XML doc comment for the field, but that will only apply to the field itself.

To add parameter names and doc comments for the delegate parameters, you need to create your own delegate type.

For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Description
/// </summary>
/// <param name="current">Param description...</param>
/// <param name="total">Param description...</param>
/// <param name="additional">Param description...</param>
public delegate void CallbackHandler(int current, int total, TaskCallbackArgs additional);
```

Comment: When I was writing this code I was thinking that I save my time using general delegates, but I had wrong :(